# Use vlookup function in Ms Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 excel files:

**file1.xlsx**
[image]

**file2.xlsx**
[image]

I want to use **vlookup** function to get the output from 2 excel files as below:
[image]

However, I am first time to use this function. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible related post with answer: https://superuser.com/a/487579

Answer (score 0):

Please use this formula in the column "code" in file1.xlsx, (C2)

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,[file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4,2)
```

Assuming the data range starts from A2, 
B2 in file1 is the customer ID "A001", and the range A2:B4 in file2 contains the data. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use this Formula in Cell C2 in File1,,

=Vlookup ([File1. Xls] Sheet1! B2, [File2. Xls] Sheet1! A2:B10, 2,FALSE)